# Manage the screen to open when calling custom URL scheme

Tags: ios, url-scheme

Creating catcher in plist. When custom URL is called from safari, the app will open. But the issue is that the app opens to that screen only from where it goes to background. I want that the app always open to home screen, no matter from which screen it goes background. 
Hope i made my point clear. Please guide for above.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add code to go back to your home screen in the `handleOpenURL` handler in your app delegate. For example, if you have a reference of your main navigation controller you can do something like

```
[navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

or in Swift

```
navigationController.popToRootViewControllerAnmiated(false)
```

The exact implementation depends on your setup.

Comment: I did tell you in the first line of my answer ... :(

Comment: can you please post proper lines of code, i have not used handleOpenURL yet.

Comment: one more thing am using storyboard, so there is no navigation controller.

Comment: This is the answer to your problem. You will have to write your app yourself ... ;-). NB: The possible existence of a navigation controller is independent from the use of storyboards.

Comment: There is a nice library for doing this: https://github.com/Wasappli/WAAppRouting It handles the controller stack for you